# Эффекты плавающих блоков на слайдере

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-animation

Добрый день, есть вопрос с реализацией такого эффекта как тут [ссылка](https://avada.theme-fusion.com/landing-product/) (самый первый блок), а именно передвижение блоков при наведении на них курсора, а также когда курсор не активен те блоки меняют свою координату. И может кто то поможет найти плагин для реализации такого например на слайдере, что бы при перелистывании слайдов координаты оставались тех блоков или просто сделать их как position: absolute и все но тогда могут как мне кажется появится проблемы...

Comment: это паралакс : https://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/yMEgYy

Comment: Да но есть так же то что этот эффект есть и без наводки на него мышью.... Мне кажется существует какой то плагин...

Comment: plugin так и называется parallax.js